# time series extraction by event onset

Tags: r, time, filter, intervals, baseline

I'm looking for a code to extract a time interval (500ms) of a column (called time) for each trial onset, so that I can calculate a baseline of the first 500ms of each trial 
actual time in ms between two consecutive rows of the column varies, because the dataset is downsampled and only changes are reported, so I cannot just count a certain number of rows to define the time interval.

I tried this:

```
baseline <- labchart   %>%
dplyr::filter(time[1:(length(labchart$time)+500)])   %>%
dplyr::group_by(Participant, trialonset)
```

but only got error messages like: 
Error: Argument 2 filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector
And I am not sure, if (time[1:(length(labchart$Time)+500)]) would really give me the first 500ms of each trial?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know exactly what you're asking here. I *think* what you're asking is how to group observations into 500ms periods given only time intervals between observations.

Suppose the data looks like this:

````r
``` r
labchart <- data.frame(time = sample(50:300, 20, TRUE), data = rnorm(20))

labchart
#>    time        data
#> 1   277 -1.33120732
#> 2   224 -0.85356280
#> 3    80 -0.32012499
#> 4   255  0.32433366
#> 5   227 -0.49600772
#> 6   248  2.23246918
#> 7   138 -1.40170795
#> 8   115 -0.76525043
#> 9   159  0.14239351
#> 10  207 -1.53064873
#> 11  139 -0.82303066
#> 12  185  1.12473125
#> 13  239 -0.22491238
#> 14  117 -0.55809297
#> 15  147  0.83225435
#> 16  200  0.75178516
#> 17  170 -0.78484405
#> 18  208  1.21000589
#> 19  196 -0.74576650
#> 20  184  0.02459359
````

Then we can create a column for total elapsed time and which 500ms period the observation belongs to like this:

```r
library(dplyr)

labchart %>% 
  mutate(elapsed = lag(cumsum(time), 1, 0), 
         period = 500 * (elapsed %/% 500))

#>    time        data elapsed period
#> 1   277 -1.33120732       0      0
#> 2   224 -0.85356280     277      0
#> 3    80 -0.32012499     501    500
#> 4   255  0.32433366     581    500
#> 5   227 -0.49600772     836    500
#> 6   248  2.23246918    1063   1000
#> 7   138 -1.40170795    1311   1000
#> 8   115 -0.76525043    1449   1000
#> 9   159  0.14239351    1564   1500
#> 10  207 -1.53064873    1723   1500
#> 11  139 -0.82303066    1930   1500
#> 12  185  1.12473125    2069   2000
#> 13  239 -0.22491238    2254   2000
#> 14  117 -0.55809297    2493   2000
#> 15  147  0.83225435    2610   2500
#> 16  200  0.75178516    2757   2500
#> 17  170 -0.78484405    2957   2500
#> 18  208  1.21000589    3127   3000
#> 19  196 -0.74576650    3335   3000
#> 20  184  0.02459359    3531   3500
```

Comment: The Data set looks like this: `Participant Time GSR Trialonset Messages
 15 2741960  35.15788  NA NA
 15 2741970  35.15400  NA NA
 15 2741980  35.15025  107 #* ClockOnset
 15 2741990  35.14600  NA NA
 15 2742000  35.14212  NA NA` So eplapsed time does not really summarise the time column correctly.. I would like to use the trialonset variable (so in this example the 107) as the starting point for the 500ms interval, extract from the time column to calculate the baseline for the GSR column. (sorry for the bad editing, I havent figured out how to use line breaks..)

Comment: the time column is more detailed (four rows for 10ms, whereas later it's 1 row for 10ms) at the start of the set though (cause there were more changes in the GSR), `Participant Time GSR Trialonset Messages
 14 0 0.197250 NA NA
 14 0 1.187000 NA NA
 14 0 1.294625 NA NA
 14 0 2.153125 NA NA
 14 10 0.890250 NA NA
 14 10 5.318625 NA NA`

Comment: @AnnaRender would you be able to add a part of the data set to your question? If you do `dput(Data[1:10,])` and copy the result into a code block in your question that should give a much clearer picture

Comment: `structure(list(Participant = c("14", "14", "14", "14", "14"), 
    time = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 10), GSR = c(0.19725, 1.187, 1.294625, 
    2.153125, 0.89025), MessagesNR = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), Messages = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
    )), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), groups = structure(list(Participant = "14", 
    .rows = list(1:5)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))` like this?